# How can I run this script when the tab reloads (chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, reload, onupdate

So i'd like to run a script when the tab reloads in a specified URL. It almost works, but actually id doesn't :)
This is my manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Sample Extension",
"description": "Sample Chrome Extension",
"version": "1.0",

"content_scripts":
[
    {
      "matches": ["http://translate.google.hu/*"],
      "js": ["run.js"]
    }
],

"permissions":
[
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
],

"browser_action":
{
    "default_title": "Sample",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
}
}
```

and this is run.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
function ( tabId, changeInfo, tab )
{
    if ( changeInfo.status === "complete" )
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {file: "program.js"} );
    }
}
);
```

The programs.js just alerts some text (yet). When I put an alert to the first line of the run.js, it alerts, but when I put it in the if, it doesn't. I can't find the problem. Did I type something wrong?

Comment: Did you check for errors in the dev console? I think you need to run this from a background page rather than the content script. I believe content scripts can only utilise chrome.extension and all other methods in the api need to be invoked on a background.js page.

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/23333771/632951

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that `http://translate.google.hu/*` pages are the ones you wish to inject code into on reload, you would have to go about it in a slightly different way. Currently you are **always** injecting code into those pages (without the permission to do so, no less) and then trying to use the `chrome.tabs` api inside that content script, which you can't do. Instead, we will put the listener in a background page and inject the code only on a page refresh, like you want. First the **manifest**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample Extension",
  "description": "Sample Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions":[
    "http://translate.google.hu/*", "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
  if (tab.url.indexOf("http://translate.google.hu/") > -1 && 
      changeInfo.url === undefined){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "program.js"} );
  }
});
```

This will listen for the `onUpdated` event, checks if it is one of the `url`'s that we want to inject into, and then it checks if the page was reloaded. That last step is accomplished by checking if `changeInfo.url` exists. If it does, then that means that the url was changed and thus not a refresh. Conversely, if it doesn't exist, then the page must have only been refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how can I run this script if there is another tab on top?

Comment: @Geiszla What do you mean by another tab on top?

Comment: So when I reload the tab, but change tab. Then the script don't run, because that is not that (e.g. translate.google.hu) website.

Comment: Great! I wrote the same function for other things for my extension, but I did not know onUpdate callback arguments. Thanks, this helped me a lot +1

Comment: @BeardFist, Are you sure this works as expected? Wouldn't this fire even for [`changeInfo.status` and etc etc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)?

Comment: I agree with @Pacerier. I'm not sure that "changeInfo.url === undefined" works as expected. It will be trigger with any change on the actual tab and not only when the tab is refreshed.

Answer (score 11):

### 2021

If you want to detect reload from background.js in manifest 3 (maybe also 2), chrome.tabs.onUpdated approach didn't work for me :/ It was invoked too many times.

That what worked for me in the end!

```
// --- On Reloading or Entering example.com --- 
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener((details) => {
    if (["reload", "link", "typed", "generated"].includes(details.transitionType) &&
        details.url === "http://example.com/") {

        codeAfterReload();

        // If you want to run only when the reload finished (at least the DOM was loaded)
        chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function onComplete() {

            codeAfterReloadAndFinishSomeLoading();

            chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(onComplete);
        });
    }
});
```

For more transition types: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/#transition_types

good luck :)

Comment: Keep in mind that these APIs require the `webNavigation` permission with shows the "This extension can see all your browsing" message

Comment: There's additional info in the second parameter of the callback: `changeInfo`. When loading the `changeInfo.status == "loading` and when loaded it is `"complete"`. By checking `changeInfo.status` you can make sure it runs once.

Answer (score 4):

`content_scripts` are run at every page (re)load, so it's best to just use those to detect it.

This way you also don't risk running any code in the `background` before your `content_script` is ready to receive any message.

Comment: There seems to be a Chrome bug whereby sometimes manifest contentscript doesn't run on page load. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191679/chrome-extension-inject-js-before-page-load/19192010#comment78166411_19192010