# Chrome extension: page loads faster than extension code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am working on the extension that needs to update page texts after page is loaded. I use **window.onload** in "**content_script**".

As I need to test my changes a lot I decided to create a **little page** with a few paragraphs of text and put it in my web server. But when this page loads - extension's **window.onload doesn't trigger**, wheres on any other internet page it works properly.

I started **investigation** and found out, that this is because of the page **loading speed**. So basically **page loads faster than extension code**.

It was **verified** by adding background image on the body linked to the external site. Like this:

```
body
{
    background: url(http://colourunity.com/img/2013/07/autumn-wallpaper-computer-14172-hd-widescreen-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

So the page's **loading speed slows down** and extension has enough time to load in and **window.onload triggers**.

Of course I don't worry about extension work, because it is too rare case when page loads that fast.

**But still - is there anyway to bypass this?**

Thanks.

Comment: The page doesn't load faster than the extension code, the browser simlpy executes the page first, then the extensions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191679/chrome-extension-inject-js-before-page-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window` object of your content script  is not the same as the one of your page. From the [content script documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment):

> It's worth noting what happens with JavaScript objects that are shared by the page and the extension - for example, the `window.onload` event. **Each isolated world sees its own version of the object.**

Therefore listening for this event in your content script won't work as you intent, since it's not the one you want.

It doesn't matter anyway: you can specify at which point your script is executed via the `run_at` option. For example, if you choose to run it at `document_idle`, then you're guaranteed it's executed after the `window.onload` event of your page.

In other words, you can simply stop using the `window.onload` event, and directly run the code you need.