# When does a run_at: document_idle content script run?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There are three options for running content scripts:

1. `document_start` - injected at the start of the `<head>`
2. `document_end` - injected right after `DOMContentLoaded`
3. `document_idle` - injected when???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According [to the current Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/renderer/script_injection_manager.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&q=f:script_injection_manager%20%22We%20try%20to%20run%20idle%20in%20two%20places%22):

> We try to run idle in two places: here and DidFinishLoad.
>   DidFinishDocumentLoad() corresponds to completing the document's load,
>   whereas DidFinishLoad corresponds to completing the document and all
>   subresources' load. We don't want to hold up script injection for a
>   particularly slow subresource, so we set a delayed task from here - but if
>   we finish everything before that point (i.e., DidFinishLoad() is
>   triggered), then there's no reason to keep waiting.

Translated into web developer speak that basically means…

`document_idle` scripts will run the earliest one of these things is true:

1. `window.onload` has fired
2. It's been **200ms** since `DOMContentLoaded` has fired.

On typical pages, these scripts will likely run at #2.