# Load Google Chrome Extenstion script after Page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, manifest

i want start my js script if the page finish to loading.

Manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "matches": [ "https://*.youtube.com/*", "http://*.youtube.com/*" ],
  "js": [
    "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
    "js/youtube.js",
    "js/function.js"
  ],
  "css": [
    "css/youtube.css"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "all_frames": false
  }
],
```

How I can start `"js/youtube.js"` and `"js/function.js"`?

The Youtube Page load but it load first my extension.

Answer (score 1):

Set value of `"run_at"` property in manifest file to `"document_idle"` (which is the default) and put your code in the content script file. Then the script will be run when the page is ready.

```
"run_at": "document_idle"
```

For more information, when `document_idle` is fires you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248629/when-does-a-run-at-document-idle-content-script-run).

Other option for you is to detect document load from background page and insert your content scripts after that. The best examples of this you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862182/on-page-load-event-in-chrome-extensions).

Comment: It's don't work well. 1 of 3 times it's load after the Website load.