# How to get instant CSS changes with Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension which changes the layout of a website. When my extension is activated and the website loads, you can briefly see the real website then it switches to my modified version loading in all the CSS and JS from the Chrome Extension. Though I've used other extensions that do something similar but have it displayed before anything actually shows the real website. One example is Shine for Reddit. When Reddit shows, it shows the extensions version of the website right at the start. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191679/chrome-extension-inject-js-before-page-load) may have your solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: Inject JS before page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191679/chrome-extension-inject-js-before-page-load)